# Открыть файл не в папке со скриптом

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Мне надо сделать приложение которое открывает файл в другой папке, не в его. Я узнала что чтоб открыть файл в другой папке нужно перед тем как писать путь написать r:

```
example = open(r"C:\\Users\\Alena\\example\\example.txt", "r")
```

Так как у пользователя может быть другой диск, и другое имя пользователя я поступила вот так вот:

```
username = os.getenv("Username")
drive = os.getenv("SystemDrive")
data = drive + "\\Users\\" + username + "\\example\\example.txt"
example = open(rdata, 'r')
```

Python думает что rdata это имя переменной, и выводит ошибку что имя rdata не найдено. Мне надо сделать чтоб переменная data была путем, а r чтоб указывало Python чтоб строка data обрабатывалась как переменная.

Comment: Python не думает, он делает то , что вы написали

Comment: Ок, как написать так чтоб пайтон сделал как я хочу?

Comment: insolor, ко второй строке , ко второй строковой литералом не получается написать r, пишет что r это не жданый символ после +

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К именам переменных `r` приписывать не нужно. `r` - это специальный синтаксис строкового литерала (т.е. строк записанных в кавычках прямо в коде), который позволяет не удваивать обратные слеши (т.е. `r` - это не магический символ, превращающий обычную строку в путь).

С `r` путь должен выглядеть так: `r"C:\Users\Alena\example\example.txt"`.

И это то же самое что такая строка: `"C:\\Users\\Alena\\example\\example.txt"`

В обоих случаях при выводе этой строки через `print` получится `C:\Users\Alena\example\example.txt`

`r"C:\\Users\\Alena\\example\\example.txt"` - это некорректный путь, в нем все слеши будут задвоены (это видно, если вывести эту строку через `print`), и файл по такому пути не получится открыть.

Чтобы исправить ваш код, просто уберите `r` перед `data`. Там, где обратные слеши и так у вас удвоены, тоже не нужно добавлять `r`. Рабочий пример:

```
username = os.getenv("Username")
drive = os.getenv("SystemDrive")
data = drive + "\\Users\\" + username + "\\example\\example.txt"
example = open(data, 'r')
```

Вообще, если нужно формировать путь из нескольких частей, удобно использовать библиотеку `pathlib`, в ней путь представлен специальным объектом `Path`, дополнительные части пути добавляются с помощью прямого слеша, пример:

```
from pathlib import Path

username = os.getenv("Username")
drive = os.getenv("SystemDrive")
data = Path(drive) / "Users" / username / "example" / "example.txt"
example = open(data, 'r')
```

Также с помощью этой библиотеки можно проще получить путь к домашней директории пользователя:

```
from pathlib import Path

data = Path.home() / "example" / "example.txt"
example = open(data, 'r')
```

Comment: `rdata` в последних двух тоже на `data` надо же поменять

Comment: Кст, у `Path` есть метод считывания из файла, получится так: `example = data.read_text()`, https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, да, синдром копипасты, поправил.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло